# Go back to previous page after submitted with id

Tags: php, html

I wonder what would the best way to make the user go back to the previous page after submitting or updating a form.

e.g From the `profile.php` page with the original id, the user then clicks on the update button which will submit the data and lead to `updateprofile.php` with the same id. After submitting the new data, the database will update based on the new given id.

Once the update is submitted, I want the user to be sent back to `profile.php` with the same id.

Comment: Did you tried any thing?? It will be easier for us to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting/updating data,get the last inserted id in updateprofile.php and return back to profile.php. 
Check this link for more info.
[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

[PHP Get ID of Last Inserted Record](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp)